# FastAPI - Pydantic validation error for nested model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

So I have a GET request that is of the format `example.com/path/get-commodities/?type=1` and it should return a JSON response in the format `{'commodities': [{'commodity_id': 1, 'commodity_name': 'Pork'}]}`. When not using this nested structure ie. just returning the value for the key `commodities`, it works normally but otherwise I am hit with a Pydantic validation error.

*path/return_schema.py* - defines the model/JSON structure for response that I need

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

# expected output: {'commodity_id': 1, 'commodity_name': 'Pork'}
class Commodities(BaseModel):
    commodity_id: int 
    commodity_name: str 

# expected output: {'commodities': [{'commodity_id': 1, 'commodity_name': 'Pork'}]}
class ReturnCommodities(BaseModel):
    commodities: List[Commodities] 

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

*path/crud.py* - where I query the DB for my results

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from .db_models import MasterCommodity, Quantity, Price # sqlalchemy models that define my database - they work anyway 

# returned output: [(1, 'Pork')]
def fetch_commodities(db:Session, type_id:int):
    if type_id == 1:
        type_commodities = [r.commodity_id for r in db.query(Price.commodity_id).distinct()]
    elif type_id == 2:
        type_commodities = [r.commodity_id for r in db.query(Quantity.commodity_id).distinct()]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid type ID")
    return db.query(MasterCommodity) \
        .with_entities(MasterCommodity.commodity_id, MasterCommodity.commodity_name) \
            .filter(MasterCommodity.commodity_id.in_(type_commodities)).all()
```

Bonus info: *path/field_schema.py* - Pydantic schemas to validate input from the GET request

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class GetCommodities(BaseModel):
    type: int
```

*path/api.py* - dedicated router & routes for this particular path

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from .field_schema import GetCommodities
from .return_schema import ReturnCommodities
from .crud import fetch_commodities
from db.sqlalchemy import SessionLocal
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/path",
    tags=["Path"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)

@router.get("/get-commodities/", response_model=ReturnCommodities)
async def get_commodities(args: GetCommodities = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return fetch_commodities(db=db, type_id=args.type)
```

On sending the GET request, I get hit with a **500 Internal Server Error**.

Stacktrace:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:56800 - "GET /path/get-commodities/?type=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 372, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 261, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 235, in app
    response_data = await serialize_response(
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 138, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ReturnCommodities
response -> commodities
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Comment: Should your `response_model` not be `List[Commodities]`?

Comment: You're returning a list of commodities, but your response format expects a dictionary with the key `commodities`. `return {'commodities: fetch_commodities(...)}`

Comment: @MatsLindh Oh okay, I was under the impression that FastAPI will use the Pydantic schema to automatically structure the response for me. So I'll just define it manually, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of defining the schema? Can someone else confirm as well?

Comment: It will do that, but you _have to give it in a format that it can map into the schema_. It can't know that what you return is supposed to go into the `commodities` key unless you give a value for - well, the commodities key. It will convert your other returned data to pydantic models according to your structure which are then serialized to JSON for the response.

Comment: Okay, so that should happen within the function in `crud.py` itself? I'll try that.

Comment: No, do that in your `api.py` file. Just return `commodities: ...` and it should map it fine. A function named `fetch_commodities` shouldn't usually have a top level key named `commodities` in its response, since that's given from the name already. If you don't need the `commodities` key, you can just return a list of Commodity objects instead.

Comment: That I already am able to. Okay, another question here itself if its okay: my next route will return something on the lines of `{commodity: 1, areas: [{states: [{id:1, name:Somestate, districts: [{id:1, name:Somedist}, ...]}, ...]}]}` - so for there do I have to define the same manually? Or is there a better way?

Comment: That depends on what you're fetching and how it is structured; if it's structure so that the properties you need map onto the schema, you're good to go. If not, you'll have to massage it so it maps (a schema defines what fields are included, etc. (fields not in the schema will be ignored) and is the basis for the generated documentation, etc.)

Comment: Maybe it is about the `type` keyword. Python already have `type` keyword for the built-in function. Instead of type, you may try something else. It may not the main problem but it's good practice to avoid using `type` as a variable name.